# How to convert fancy box to fancy box gallery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, image-gallery

I create [this](http://hmahdavi.zgig.ir/#fh5co-features) website and use fancy box for show images with effect. I want convert this images to image gallery . My images in my website placed into codes such as this :

```
<div class="col-md-4   to-animate popup text-center fadeInUp animated">
                    <br>
                    <a href="images/best-Exporter-91.jpg" class="fancybox">
                        <img src="images/best-Exporter-91.jpg" class="center-block img img-responsive"></a>
                    <h4 class="center-block">Best Exporter Award 2012</h4>
                </div>
```

I use this jquery foe run  fancy box :

```
  /***************** Initiate Fancybox ******************/

    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        padding: 4,
    });
```

Exist a sample for fancy box gallery in [this](http://fancybox.net/). I  want create a image gallery such as it. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: do you mean you want the previous and next buttons to show when you open the gallery?

Comment: Yes ................

Comment: Please refer to my answer, that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `rel="gallery1"` to group the images:

```
<div class="col-md-4   to-animate popup text-center fadeInUp animated">
   <br>
   <a href="images/best-Exporter-91.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery1">
   <img src="images/best-Exporter-91.jpg" class="center-block img img-responsive"></a>
   <h4 class="center-block">Best Exporter Award 2012</h4>

   <br>
   <a href="images/best-Exporter-91.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery1">
   <img src="images/best-Exporter-91.jpg" class="center-block img img-responsive"></a>
   <h4 class="center-block">Best Exporter Award 2012</h4>

   <br>
   <a href="images/best-Exporter-91.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery1">
   <img src="images/best-Exporter-91.jpg" class="center-block img img-responsive"></a>
   <h4 class="center-block">Best Exporter Award 2012</h4>
</div>
```